# Scheduling PowerShell script in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure

What is the best way of scheduling a PowerShell script in Azure? Should I create a VM and schedule it via a task scheduler. Or is there any better way?

I have a PowerShell script that I extracts data from audit log and reports some information. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Azure Automation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/). Its easy to use and you can run jobs for 500 minutes for free (every month).

Comment: Thank you  Isaak. Does it also support sending the output file to an office 365 email address?